# Como resolver System.TypeInitializationException?

Tags: c#, excepciones

Tengo una clase estática

```
namespace Metropolitano
{
public static class Rutas
{
    public static SAlimentadora AlimentadoraSur = new SAlimentadora();
    private static BAlimentador Cedros02 = new BAlimentador();
    private static BAlimentador Villa04 = new BAlimentador();
    private static BAlimentador America07 = new BAlimentador();
    private static BAlimentador Proceres08 = new BAlimentador();
    private static BAlimentador busTest = new BAlimentador();
    public static SAlimentadora AlimentadoraNorte = new SAlimentadora();

    static Rutas()
    {
            AlimentadoraSur.Estaciones = new[]
            {
            //AS-02 Cedros de Villa 0-10
            "Terminal Matellini", "Huaylas", "Alameda Sur", "Los Pinos",
            "Plaza Vea", "Las Camelias",
            "Cedros de Villa", "Ballestas", "España", "Aruba",
             .
             .
             .
```

Y al ejecutar me bota

> System.TypeInitializationExcepcion "Se produjo una excepción en el
>   inicializador de tipo de 'Metropolitano.Rutas'."

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbDestinoAS.Enabled = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < **AlimentadoraSur.Estaciones.Length**; i++) //El error ocurre aqui
        {
            cmbInicioAS.Items.Add($"{i}-{AlimentadoraSur.Estaciones[i]}");
            cmbDestinoAS.Items.Add($"{i}-{AlimentadoraSur.Estaciones[i]}");
        }
    }
```

Ya he debugeado pero no encontré nada y leí por ahí que se puede resolver con un `try catch` pero no me funciona tampoco. ¿Cómo hago desaparecer ese error?

Comment: Pero resolver el problema, hay que entender la causa. Y para que nosotros podamos entender la causa, necesitamos poder reproducir el error también. Pero para esto, necesitas proveer un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  En otras palabras, incluye una versión completa pero simplificada de tu código que aísle el problema, y que nosotros podemos ejecutar para identificar el problema.

Comment: También, junto con el error, siempre deberías incluir el "stack trace" completo. Allí se encuentra mucha información valiosa.

Comment: Necesitariamos tambien ver el codigo de la clase `SAlimentadora`

Comment: ...Y el de `BAlimentador`. El error es probable que esté en el constructor de alguna de las dos clases